# Retrieving column data in MySQL with data type DATETIME turns the data into ISO format

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Logging the date and time after doing a query on one of my tables in MySQL is coming up in ISO format.  This becomes a problem because the way that the time is being inserted into the database is from using MySQL NOW() function which looks like it inserts the time in UTC (which in my local time is 5 hours ahead).  So when I retrieve the data from the database, now the date is another 5 hours ahead of the UTC time, which makes it slightly difficult to change this time back to my local time.

The format that the date/time is being inserted into the database is: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
The example I'm working with is 2019-09-13 00:26:12

I run the query "SELECT * From mytable"  from within my code.  This query gets put into an array, and I can then access the field by myarray.tempdate.

When I console log this in my application I get *2019-09-13T05:26:12.000Z* which looks like it's in ISO format which would add another 5 hours, but why?  I'm not sure why when logging this date it treats it as UTC instead of a string, which is what I expected to get.  If anyone knows why this is happening I would me much appreciative.  Thank You!

Comment: What is the datatype of the concerned column ? Please publish results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`

Comment: The "Z" means "Zulu time", or UTC. UTC times are strings. Instead of `NOW()` use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`.

Comment: If you know the stored/desired timezones, you can use convert_tz: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya the data type is DATETIME

Comment: Shouldn't be UTC by default, should be TZ of server.